# Geometric cipher... somehow

Tags: cipher

I've got a message for you. It's hard to decrypt (I think), but you will like what's said to you. Here's the message:

> XXRKUXIQXXXXLLRYIXRVYXIIXPVZXAQKYIXHPSCZWEIJFXGYIXHCHSHGIXXMXIEURIRUEBHIXIXREOXCNLTTTXI

And here are the hints:

Hint 1:

> Three. And a bit of int arithmetic being used rarely.

Hint 2:

> What are the similarities of A and K or S and J?

Comment: A,K or S,J have no visible similarities if expressed in Ascii,hex,oct,binary ?

Comment: A and K each made of 3-pieces of straight line segments. S and J both contains curve. That may be a similarity; as well op declares it is "geometric puzzle".

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Wrong too. U is also in the group of A and K.

Comment: A, K and U are letters 1, 11 and 21, all ending in 1. That doesn't work for J and S, though..

Comment: @Levieux not on purpose, too. D would be in the same group. Look at the letters itself!

Comment: So we're looking for similarities in the shapes of letters A, D, K and U? Nothing jumps out to me at the moment.

Comment: @Levieux how do you get something like an |- of an H?

Comment: @Mega Man: You mean these letters are all symmetrical? (although A has vertical symmetry, whereas the others have horizontal symmetry) What about S and J. S has point symmetry and J is not symmetric at all

Comment: @Levieux You're on the right way with symmetrics. 1 sheep, 2 sheep, 3 sheep... What am I doing?

Comment: @Mega Man Other than that I have to treat the letters in groups of three and that plural equals singular I have no idea

Comment: @Levieux I'm cou..... XD And you should do that too with your symmetries

Comment: @MegaMan Alright, so I count a total of 66 symmetrical letters. Dividing this in groups of 29 (as the first hint might suggest), there are 21-21-24 per group. What am I to do with this information?

Comment: It's way to compicated, I answer myself.

Comment: @MegaMan: You plan on writing the answer here? I'm curious to know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1

First, divide the chars in groups of three, like this:

> XXR KUX IQX XXX LLR YIX RVY XII XPV ZXA QKY IXH PSC ZWE IJF XGY IXH CHS HGI XXM XIE URI RUE BHI XIX REO XCN LTT TXI

Then, count the axial symmetries on every char and transform the chars to numbers:

> 220 112 202 222 000 122 011 222 201 021 011 222 001 011 200 201 222 120 202 221 221 102 011 122 222 012 210 011 122

Now, try to see the numbers ternal, with number base 3:

> 24 14 20 26 0 17 4 26 19 7 4 26 1 4 18 19 26 15 20 25 25 11 4 17 26 5 21 4 17

Now this represents the alphabet, 0-indized, and 26 is space key:

> YOU ARE THE BEST PUZZLER EVER
>
>  and I made a mistake I didn't notice myself: It resulted in the code for
>
>  YOU ARE THE BEST PUZZLER FVER
>  Sorry. And I am not :)

Comment: I think this would have been impossible to do without any clues and with the current clues.

Comment: Difficulty notwithstanding, with some fonts, including this one, K is not perfectly symmetrical about any axis. The difference is slight. Also O, if it is a circle is symmetrical across infinitely many axes.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

- > There's a total of 87 characters, which can be split op into 29 rows/columns of three (hence the hint maybe?).
- > Could the similarities of Hint 2 possibly refer to what these letters are made up of? A and K both consist of 3 straight lines. S and J both consist of one curved line.
- > There's lots of X's (and also I's). Most of the I's are next to an X (11 out of 13), so perhaps this is related to Roman numerals??

Comment: Well, the first one is good, but the others aren't really true.

Comment: That last line is incorrect, completely. ONLY 1 I can be in front of an X or a V, so the IIX is incorrect. Also the letters, listed in increasing value, are: I, V, X, L, C, D, and M, for 1,5,10,50,100,500,1000 respectively. Also the starting XXXXLL is illegal for 2 reasons: like the above rule, 1 X can only exist before an L or a C, and 2 L's do not make a C. I cannot unfortunately fit all the rules of roman numerals in this comment, but take a look at Wikipedia.

Comment: Frequency analysis to add to this x = 21; i = 13; r = 6; h = 5; e, y = 4; l, t, u, c = 3; p, q, z, g, s, v, k = 2; 
w, m, f, b, o, i, a, n, d = 1.

Also xi(5), ix(7) and xx(4) are the only repeated sequences so look key to this puzzle - probably signifying the type of integer arithmetic to do

Comment: @DeepPurple: your second i should be a j. Also, d doesn't occur at all, it's the only letter that's not in there.

Comment: @Levieux It wasn't on purpose D isn't there.